# jenkins plugin connection refused

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, plugins, connection

I have the following snippet that is part of a Jenkins plugin listed below. The problem is that when running it, I am getting **"connection refused"**. I am using a Tomcat web server on Ubuntu 16.0.4. It is being hosted on vultr.

**The error message (from the console) is listed below** - the connection is refused so nothing else can take place

I have also tried the actual IP address and "localhost"

```
Started by user admin
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/testagain
Building WAR file for Project...
Opening WaveMaker project: Project
Sending WaveMaker a message: {"params":["Project"],"method":"openProject","id":5}
FATAL: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:8094 refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579
```

)

**The code being called is as follows:**

```
        private boolean sendWaveMakerRequest(String serviceUrl,
                DefaultHttpClient client, String json, String expectedResponse,
                BuildListener listener) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
                IOException, ClientProtocolException {
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);
```

`listener.getLogger().println("Sending WaveMaker a message: " + json);

        HttpResponse response = sendRequest(client, json, postRequest);

        if (!checkWaveMakerStatus(listener, response)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!checkWaveMakerReason(listener, response)) {
            return false;
        }

        return checkJsonResponse(expectedResponse, listener, response);
    }`

**Question: What can I do to solve the problem?**
TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the proxy server that Jenkins will use by going to Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced. This is preferred over setting JVM properties.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy